# Invoking C compiler using Python subprocess command

Tags: python, c, shell

I am trying to compile a C program using Python and want to give input using "<" operator but it's not working as expected.
If I compile the C program and run it by giving input though a file it works; for example

```
./a.out <inp.txt works
```

But similarly if I try to do this using a Python script, it did not quite work out as expected.
For example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["gcc","a.c","-o","x"])
subprocess.call(["./x"])
```

and

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["gcc","a.c","-o","x"])
subprocess.call(["./x","<inp.txt"])
```

Both script ask for input though terminal. But I think in the second script it should read from file. why both the programs are working the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To complement [@Jonathan Leffler's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24738278/45375) and [@alastair's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24738400/45375) helpful answers:

Assuming *you* control the string you're passing to the shell for execution, I see nothing wrong with using the shell for convenience. <sup>[1]</sup>

**`subprocess.call()` has an optional Boolean `shell` parameter, which causes the command to be passed to the *shell***, enabling I/O redirection, referencing environment variables, ...:

```py
subprocess.call("./x <inp.txt", shell = True)
```

Note how the **entire command line is passed as a *single* string** rather than an array of arguments.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>
**Avoid use of the shell in the following cases:**

- If your Python code **must run on platforms *other* than Unix-like ones, such as Windows**.
- If performance is paramount.
- If you find yourself "outsourcing" tasks better handled on the Python side.

**If you're concerned about lack of predictability of the shell environment** (as @alastair is):

- `subprocess.call` with `shell = True` ***always* creates non-interactive non-login instances of `/bin/sh`** - note that it is NOT the *user's* default shell that is used.
- `sh` **does NOT read initialization files** for non-interactive non-login shells (neither system-wide nor user-specific ones).

  - Note that even on platforms where `sh` is `bash` in disguise, `bash` will act this way when invoked as `sh`.
- Every shell instance created with `subprocess.call` with `shell = True` is its own world, and its environment is neither influenced by previous shell instances nor does it influence later ones.
- However, the **shell instances created *do* inherit the *environment of the python process itself***:

  - If you started your Python program from an interactive shell, then that shell's environment is inherited. Note that this only **pertains to the *current working directory* and *environment variables***, and NOT to aliases, shell functions, and shell variables.
  - **Generally, that's a *feature***, given that Python (CPython) itself is designed to be controllable via environment variables (for 2.x, see https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables; for 3.x, see https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables).
  - **If needed, you can *supply your own environment*** to the shell via the `env` parameter; note, however, that **you'll have to supply the *entire* environment in that event**, potentially including variables such as `USER` and `HOME`, if needed; simple example, defining `$PATH` explicitly:

    ```py
    subprocess.call('echo $PATH', shell = True, \
                    env = { 'PATH': '/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin' })
    ```

Comment: Is there “nothing wrong with using the shell for convenience”?  You'd think so, but what happens if e.g. the user sets IFS?  Or, since the calls above to gcc don't specify a full path, PATH?  It really is better not to use the shell to run things if you can possibly avoid it.

Comment: @alastair: `$IFS` or `$PATH` could only be changed (temporarily) from the very same shell command you're executing; see my update on how the shell instances are created and let me know if you still have concerns about a modified environment (I may well be missing something). That said, a compelling reason to avoid the shell is if you also need to support Windows (unless you deliberately use only commands simple enough to work on both platform types).

Comment: According to the `subprocess` docs, unless an environment is explicitly specified, it’s inherited from the Python process.  If someone can manipulate the environment of *that* process, it could still cause unwanted behaviour.

Comment: @alastair: That is worth noting, but that's more of a _feature_ than a pitfall - see my update.

Comment: Sure. I still think using the shell from code is generally to be discouraged, especially where there's a simple non-shell-based alternative available.  That said, I've up voted your answer because it's now quite comprehensive IMO :-)

Comment: @alastair: Thank you. It's our exchange here that encouraged me to look into this more - and I do see your point. Hopefully there is now enough information here for everyone to make an informed decisions about whether using the shell is right for their needs.

Answer (score 4):

The shell does I/O redirection for a process.  Based on what you're saying, the `subprocess` module does not do I/O redirection like that.  To demonstrate, run:

```
subprocess.call(["sh","-c", "./x <inp.txt"])
```

That runs the shell and should redirect the I/O.  With your code, your program `./x` is being given an argument `<inp.txt` which it is ignoring.

NB: the alternative call to `subprocess.call` is purely for diagnostic purposes, not a recommended solution.  The recommended solution involves reading the (Python 2) [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module documentation (or the [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) documentation for it) to find out how to do the redirection using the module.

```
import subprocess
i_file = open("inp.txt")
subprocess.call("./x", stdin=i_file)
i_file.close()
```

If your script is about to exit so you don't have to worry about wasted file descriptors, you can compress that to:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("./x", stdin=open("inp.txt"))
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `subprocess` module does not pass the arguments to the shell.  Why?  Because running commands via the shell is *dangerous*; unless they're correctly quoted and escaped (which is complicated), it is often possible to convince programs that do this kind of thing to run unwanted and unexpected shell commands.

Using the shell for this would be wrong anyway.  If you want to take input from a particular file, you can use `subprocess.Popen`, setting the `stdin` argument to a file descriptor for the file `inp.txt` (you can get the file descriptor by calling `fileno()` a Python file object).