# Using subprocess for compiling a c++ program from python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, subprocess, root-framework

I know there are some similar questions, here [Invoking C compiler using Python subprocess command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738107/invoking-c-compiler-using-python-subprocess-command) and [subprocess, invoke C-program from within Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541728/subprocess-invoke-c-program-from-within-python) but I believe my question is in some sense different.

I need to compile a c++ program which uses some [ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/) libraries so I need to add some flags and link some libraries for the compilation. Therefore my compilation line on the normal shell is:

```
> $($ROOTSYS/bin/root-config --cxx) $($ROOTSYS/bin/root-config --cflags --glibs) Analysis.cxx -o analysis.exe
```

which works nicely. I want to do this compilation from my python script. I have read the documentation for the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module but I could not get a solution without using `shell=True` in the call of subprocess.Popen and I do not really undestand the difference. If I use:

```
process = Popen(["$($ROOTSYS/bin/root-config --cxx) $($ROOTSYS/bin/root-config --cflags --glibs) Analysis.cxx -o analysis.exe"], shell=True)
```

does the job. However, this:

```
process = Popen(["$($ROOTSYS/bin/root-config --cxx)", "$($ROOTSYS/bin/root-config --cflags --glibs)", "Analysis.cxx", "-o", "analysis.exe"])
```

I got the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_posanalysis.py", line 45, in <module>
    "Analysis.cxx", "-o", "analysis.exe"])
  File "Python/2.7.15/x86_64-slc6-gcc62-opt/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "Python/2.7.15/x86_64-slc6-gcc62-opt/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I would like to understand the difference between using/not using `shell=True` since it seems to be the reason behind making the script work or not. Or, is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
> ```

So it'e executing something equivalent to:

```
/bin/sh -c '$($ROOTSYS/bin/root-config --cxx)' '$($ROOTSYS/bin/root-config --cflags --glibs)' "Analysis.cxx", "-o", "analysis.exe"
```

This isn't what you want, because it only performs `$(...)` expansion in the first argument; everything else is taken literally, and become the positional arguments if the command in the first argument refers to `$1`, `$2`, etc.

If you want everything parsed by the shell, just give a single string.

Comment: So if I got it right, there is no way to do it without the shell=True because I need to perform two `$(...)` expansions?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You could execute those commands yourself, save the output, and then build the command from that.

Comment: So basically the only truly shell interaction (call the shell command, not sure if I can called it "interaction") happens with the first argument if I pass the command as a list. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you pass the command as a list, the first element is treated as the shell command, the rest are arguments. If you pass it as a string, the whole string is a shell command.